# rspec+devise: current_user is missing attribute methods when rspec is ran

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

This is one of the filter method that is ran when edit method is ran for Users controller

```rb
def correct_user?(post)
  post.user == current_user || current_user.admin
end
```

This is the test I am running

```rb
describe PostsController do
  subject { page }

  let(:first_user_is_admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  describe "Admin user see edit view of someone else's post:" do
    before do 
      sign_in first_user_is_admin
      visit edit_post_path(post)
    end

    describe "Post is not anonymous with user_id" do
      let(:post) { FactoryGirl.create(:post, :user => first_user_is_admin) }
      before do
        visit edit_post_path(post)
      end
      it { current_path.should == edit_post_path(post) }
    end
  end
end
```

---

When this test runs, it fails because

```
 Failure/Error: visit edit_post_path(post)
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `admin' for nil:NilClass
```

I find this to be strange because `post.user == current_user` part of the code is ok. So current_user is probably not nil or something.

Anyone have any idea why I am getting this undefined method error only during rspec test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is here

```
visit edit_post_path(post)
```

You haven't told it what post is or what it refers to.  it is expecting post to contain something.

It may be because your `let` block is declared after the first call to post.

Comment: That's a legitimate error on my part. Thanks for finding that. I removed that bit but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Ok, perhaps it's the `def correct_user?(post)
  post.user == current_user || current_user.admin
end` section.  Does this method work if you test it in `rails console`?  From the looks of the error message it is failing to find current user so jumps to the other side of the || where it is calling .admin on an object that doesn't exist, hence the `undefined method `admin' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Silly me! The test error was for some other test in the same file! Thanks for the help still